# Loop array by parameteres from another array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of permissions

```
const permissions = ['search', 'reports', 'whitelist'];
```

and I have a menus

```
const menus = [
  {
    text: 'Navigation',
    link: 'navigation',
    topic: 'all',
  },
  {
    text: 'Dictionary',
    link: 'dict',
    topic: 'src',
  },
  {
    text: 'Services',
    link: '/services',
    submenu: [
      {
        text: 'Check company',
        link: '/services/search',
        topic: 'search',
      },
      {
        text: 'Report statistic',
        link: '/services/reportstatistic',
        topic: 'another-topic',
      },
      {
        text: 'Report request',
        link: '/services/getrequestreport',
        topic: 'another-topic-2',
      },
      {
        text: 'Get whitelist',
        link: '/services/getresponsereport',
        topic: 'whitelist',
      },
      {
        text: 'Get data',
        link: '/services/requestdata',
        topic: 'reports',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need to filter `menus` to check each item of array if it has `topic` equals to one of permission from `permissions` array and if it has `submenu` then check each item form submenu for same or if `topic ==='all'` and add the one to new menu anyway.
Expecting result after filter is

```
const newArrr = [
  {
    text: 'Navigation',
    link: 'navigation',
    topic: 'all',
  },
  {
    text: 'Services',
    link: '/services',
    submenu: [
      {
        text: 'Check company',
        link: '/services/search',
        topic: 'search',
      },
      {
        text: 'Get whitelist',
        link: '/services/getresponsereport',
        topic: 'whitelist',
      },
      {
        text: 'Get data',
        link: '/services/requestdata',
        topic: 'reports',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I was trying to make own loop , but it is not correct

```
for (let menu of menus) {
  for (let permission of filteredPermissions) {
    if (menu.topic && (menu.topic == permission || menu.topic === 'all')) {
      newArr.push(menu);
    }
    if (menu.submenu) {
      for (let submenu of menu.submenu) {
        for (let permissionSecond of filteredPermissions) {
          if (!(submenu.topic == permissionSecond) || !(submenu == 'all')) {
            menu.submenu.splice(menu.submenu[submenu], 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd do it - first filter the parent array by whether the `.topic` is included in the permissions, then iterate through the results which have `submenu` arrays and reassign the subarray property to a filtered version:

```js
const permissions = ['search', 'reports', 'whitelist'];
permissions.push('all');

const menus=[{text:"Navigation",link:"navigation",topic:"all"},{text:"Dictionary",link:"dict",topic:"src"},{text:"Services",link:"/services",submenu:[{text:"Check company",link:"/services/search",topic:"search"},{text:"Report statistic",link:"/services/reportstatistic",topic:"another-topic"},{text:"Report request",link:"/services/getrequestreport",topic:"another-topic-2"},{text:"Get whitelist",link:"/services/getresponsereport",topic:"whitelist"},{text:"Get data",link:"/services/requestdata",topic:"reports"}]}];

const filteredMenus = menus.filter(
  item => !item.topic || permissions.includes(item.topic)
);
filteredMenus
  .filter(item => item.submenu)
  .forEach(item => item.submenu = item.submenu.filter(
    subitem => permissions.includes(subitem.topic)
  ));
console.log(filteredMenus);
```

Comment: can you please add the following object to menu in your code {
  text: 'Company',
  submenu: [
    {
      text: 'Profile',
      link: '/services/companyprofile',
      topic: 'another-topic-1321'
    },
    {
      text: 'Client',
      link: '/services/profileuserprofileclient',
      topic: 'lololo'
    }
  ]
}
for some reason I receive in last filteredMenus this {text: Company, submenu: []}

Comment: If you want empty submenu arrays to be removed, then add in afterwards `.filter(item => !item.submenu || item.submenu.length)` after the `.forEach`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.reduce` to process the `menus` array, checking if the topic is `all` or included in `permissions`, and filtering submenu values according to the same rule:

```js
const permissions = ['search', 'reports', 'whitelist'];

const menus=[{text:"Navigation",link:"navigation",topic:"all"},{text:"Dictionary",link:"dict",topic:"src"},{text:"Services",link:"/services",submenu:[{text:"Check company",link:"/services/search",topic:"search"},{text:"Report statistic",link:"/services/reportstatistic",topic:"another-topic"},{text:"Report request",link:"/services/getrequestreport",topic:"another-topic-2"},{text:"Get whitelist",link:"/services/getresponsereport",topic:"whitelist"},{text:"Get data",link:"/services/requestdata",topic:"reports"}]}];

const includeMenu = (menu) => menu.topic == 'all' || permissions.includes(menu.topic);

const newArr = menus.reduce((c, m) => {
  if (m.submenu) {
    submenus = m.submenu.filter(includeMenu);
    if (submenus.length) {
      c.push({
        text: m.text,
        link: m.link,
        submenu: submenus
      });
    }
  } else if (includeMenu(m)) {
    c.push(m);
  }
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```